# Is there a way to forcefully echo to the command-line from a bash function call?

Tags: bash, shell, echo, stdout

I've got a bash script where I define a bunch of functions in good programming style.  These functions "return" values by `echo`-ing them.  So, for example:

```
some_function() {
   echo "I like pie."
}

what_do_i_like=`some_function`
```

Now, I'd like to add in some debugging statements to my functions.  Unfortunately, anything I `echo` just gets caught by the caller in the variable.  e.g.,

```
some_function() {
    if [[ "${DEBUG}" = "${TRUE}" ]]; then
        echo "We're about to find out what we like."
    fi
    echo "I like pie."
}

what_do_i_like=`some_function`
```

... The debug statement gets caught in the `what_do_i_like` variable.

Is there any way I can bypass this and forcibly print to the command-line *and* have the output not be caught in the variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo "We're about to find out what we like." >/dev/tty
```

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't echo to stderr work? `echo 1>&2 message`

Comment: Yeah, I just don't really want to print things to STDERR which aren't actually errors.

Comment: stderr is used for *diagnostic* messages, which don't have to be just errors.

Answer (score 2):

There is a shell command interface for syslog(3):

```
logger -p DEBUG Hi there
```